# How to iterate through different dictionaries each time you loop inside a for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

My question is each time my program iterates through a for loop, is it possible to change the dictionary it is processing (in this case adding information to). i.e. first time it iterates through dict_1, then dict_2 etc.

```
def getDicts(aFile):
    voteFile = open(aFile)
    listDicts = [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
    i = 0
    for line in voteFile:
        lineSplit = line.split(':')
        if len(lineSplit) > 1:
            key = lineSplit[0].strip()
            value = lineSplit[1].strip()
            listDicts[i][key] = value
        else:
            i += 1
    return listDicts
```

The file the program is processing contains blocks of text where each line has two terms separated by a colon. After each block there is a new line. This is why there is a while loop checking for when the length of terms on each line is not 2. When the program exits the while loop I want it to add the completed dictionary (dict_1) to the list of dictionaries, and then start again on the next block of text within the .txt file, this time adding the information to dict_2.

**Complete .txt data as requested:**

```
_Constituency:East Midlands
_Seats:5
Brexit Party:452321
Liberal Democrats:203989
Labour:164682
Conservative:126138
Green:124630
UKIP:58198
Change UK:41117
Independent Network:7641
Simon Rood (Independent):4511

_Constituency:East of England
_Seats:7
Brexit Party:604715
Liberal Democrats:361563
Green:202460
Conservative:163830
Labour:139490
Change UK:58274
UKIP:54676
English Democrat:10217
Attila Csordas (Independent):3230

_Constituency:London
_Seats:8
Liberal Democrats:608725
Labour:536810
Brexit Party:400257
Green:278957
Conservative:177964
Change UK:117635
UKIP:46497
Animal Welfare:25232
Women's Equality:23766
UK EU:18806
Claudia Mcdowell (Independent):1036
Daze Aghaji (Independent):1018
Roger Hallam (Independent):924
Kofi Klu (Independent):869
Andrea Venzon (Independent):731
Mike Shad (Independent):707
Zoe Lafferty (Independent):436
Andrew Medhurst (Independent):430
Alan Kirkby (Independent):401
Ian Sowden (Independent):254
Henry Muss (Independent):226

_Constituency:North East England
_Seats:3
Brexit Party:240056
Labour:119931
Liberal Democrats:104330
Green:49905
Conservative:42395
UKIP:38269
Change UK:24968

_Constituency:North West England
_Seats:8
Brexit Party:541843
Labour:380193
Liberal Democrats:297507
Green:216581
Conservative:131002
UKIP:62464
Change UK:47237
Tommy Robinson (Independent):38908
English Democrat:10045
UK EU:7125
Mohammad Aslam (Independent):2002

_Constituency:South East England
_Seats:10
Brexit Party:915686
Liberal Democrats:653743
Green:343249
Conservative:260277
Labour:184678
Change UK:105832
UKIP:56487
UK EU:7645
Jason Guy Spencer McMahon (Independent):3650
Socialist (GB):3505
David Victor Round (Independent):2606
Michael Jeffrey Turberville (Independent):1587

_Constituency:South West England
_Seats:6
Brexit Party:611742
Liberal Democrats:385095
Green:302364
Conservative:144674
Labour:108100
UKIP:53739
Change UK:46612
English Democrat:8393
Larch Maxey (Independent):1772
Mothiur Rahman (Independent):755
Neville Seed (Independent):3383

_Constituency:West Midlands
_Seats:7
Brexit Party:507152
Labour:228298
Liberal Democrats:219982
Green:143520
Conservative:135279
UKIP:66934
Change UK:45673

_Constituency:Yorkshire and the Humber
_Seats:6
Brexit Party:470351
Labour:210516
Liberal Democrats:200180
Green:166980
Conservative:92863
UKIP:56100
Yorkshire Party:50842
Change UK:30162
English Democrat:11283

_Constituency:Scotland
_Seats:6
SNP:594553
Brexit Party:233006
Liberal Democrats:218285
Conservative:182476
Labour:146724
Scottish Green:129603
Change UK:30004
UKIP:28418
Gordon Edgar (Independent):6128
Ken Parke (Independent):2049

_Constituency:Wales
_Seats:4
Brexit Party:271404
Plaid Cymru:163928
Labour:127833
Liberal Democrats:113885
Conservative:54587
Green:52660
UKIP:27566
Change UK:24332
```

Comment: Hey there. I think this is more a problem of data structure design rather than a question of whether or not it's possible to send different dictionaries into your `for` loop (or a function). Take a step back and have a think about what kind of data structure you want. I suggest 1 dictionary with the key being the constituency and the values being another nested dictionary with keys being party and values being votes.

Comment: You are allowed to put dictionaries into a list. You could have `dicts = [{}, {}, ...]` and then `dicts[i][key] = value`

Comment: @Blorgbeard oh my that might work why didn't I think of that thank you

Comment: Please share code/data as text in the post itself, not as images.

Comment: Could you explain what your program is meant to do? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @raffoth if you could provide a sample of your .txt file, that would be helpful for others to test their solutions

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I'd suggest:

```
def getConstituencies(aFile):

    all_data = {}
    constituency_keys = []
    constituency_idx = []

    # Store all of the information in the text file
    with open(aFile, 'rb') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    # Go through the stored info and find all of the constituencies and corresponding indexes
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.split(':')[0] = '_Constituency':
            constituency_keys.append(line.split(':')[1])
            constituency_idx.append(idx)

    # Now go through the stored lines and from the specified index until a blank line, store all the related info into a dictionary. 
    # Then, nest that dictionary into the all_data dictionary
    for idx, c in zip(constituency_idx, constituency_keys):
        temp_dict = {}
        for line in lines[idx+1:]:
            if line == "":
                break
            temp_dict[line.split(':')[0]] = line.split(':')[1]
        all_data[c] = temp_dict
```

Accessing the information is then a matter of querying the constituency:

```
all_data['East Midlands']['Green']
```

I'd also suggest looking at [Pandas](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe/) to start sorting your data into DataFrames - this will make your life a lot easier with data processing

Suggestions and feedback welcome from other users.

Comment: Taking you up on _Suggestions and feedback welcome from other users._ There isn't much a point in using `readlines()` and then iterating over the list of lines, when you can just do `for line in file_obj:` directly. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: That's fair. A more concise solution would be to do a single loop and then have a series of checks to see if the line is empty or contains the string `'_Constituency'`.

Comment: Do you think using regex might be worth it here?

Comment: I think regex may be a bit of overkill for this situation - depending on the data structure we want to make, the only things we need to keep our eyes on are the underscores and colons. What do you think?

Comment: Hard to tell without more of OP's data. I do think that we could design something which returns all the `party:votes` pairs as groups, which would be really practical. I hope OP shares their data, I would love to give it a shot.